# how to provide relative path in eclipse while running in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

I wrote java code using REST which retrieves the employee details like id and name from a saved file. Absolute path is working fine while running the tomcat server, but once i provide relative path tomcat is not finding the file path. I'm using BufferedReader to read from the file.

Comment: Would you please mind to provide necessary technical details rather than being theoretical one?

Comment: please share project structure

Comment: public class UserDao {

 private static final String path = "./resources/list.txt";

 // returns all records from file
 public List<User> getUser(String id) {
  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

  File file = new File(path);
  String readLine;
  try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
   while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    User user = new User(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), split[1]);
      userList.add(user);
    }
    }
    }
    }

Comment: @michealjackson Is the list.txt file kept in your project directory? Could please show your project structure and list.txt file path.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help!
I resolved it like String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./resources/list.txt").getPath();
String fullpath=fullPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse server plugin will compile the java sources into binary class files and put it into a `work` dir, so the relative path will not working. The quickest way to make it work is to put your files into the source directory. Then Eclipse server plugin will copy that file to the classes folder in your work directory. Then you can use relative path to read it.